# Gitlab import: Could not locate Gemfile

Tags: gitlab

I have a test VM with Debian Wheezy and no ruby installed. Gitlab 6.9.2 has been installed using the provided installer which brings an embedded ruby. Now, I want to import some old repos into Gitlab, but I cannot find the correct procedure. I think it should be this way:

```
su - git
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin
cd ~
bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production
```

Though, I only get the error "Could not locate Gemfile". I have tried several other ways, also installing Debians ruby, searched multiple Google and StackOverflow results, but I couldn´t get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first place the **bare** repos in the repo dir. The [default path](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#storing-git-data-in-an-alternative-directory) for omnibus is `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<namespace>`. Then you just run the rake task:

```
sudo -u git -H cp -r my-project/.git /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<namespace>/my-project.git
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos
```

See [invoking rake tasks](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#invoking-rake-tasks) and the [import mechanism](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/import.html).

Edit: Sent an [MR upstream](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/merge_requests/142) to include this info in the readme.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into same issue with "Could not locate Gemfile". So I searched for Gemfile and tried several folders. Until it worked.

The solution is related to Gitlab from source (or in my case it run inside [offical docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/)).

Place your .git bare repository (or several of them) in 
"/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories//my-project.git"

switch to user "git".

```
su git
```

Try if you have correct PATH by just "rake". If not available, extend your PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin
```

after that switch to the shell were the rake command to import your bare projects will work and do the import.

```
cd /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/
bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production
```

Output will be similar to this:

```
Processing raspberry/apollo-web.git
 * Created apollo-web (raspberry/apollo-web.git)
Processing raspberry/apollo-web.wiki.git
 * Skipping wiki repo
Processing dhbw/dhbw-prototyping-node-rest-course.git
...
```

*EDIT:*
Ok I was happy a bit too early. Although the ouput says it was imported. On the Web GUI no new projects.

I will investiage further...

Comment: Ok I was happy a bit too early. Although the ouput says it was imported. On the Web GUI no new projects.

I will investiage further...